# Can not configure CoreOS cluster properly

Tags: coreos

I am stuck on configuring CoreOS cluster.

My cloud_config file is the next for both of VMs:

```
#cloud-config

ssh_authorized_keys:
  - ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAA...

hostname: core001

coreos:
 etcd2:
  name: core001
  discovery: https://discovery.etcd.io/86567bce070bd5316bdc9357ee2600de
  # private networking need to use $public_ipv4:
  advertise-client-urls: http://192.168.128.156:2379,http://192.168.128.156:4001
  initial-advertise-peer-urls: http://192.168.128.156:2380
  # listen on the official ports 2379, 2380 and one legacy port 4001:
  listen-client-urls: http://0.0.0.0:2379,http://0.0.0.0:4001
  listen-peer-urls: http://192.168.128.156:2380

 fleet:
  public-ip: 192.168.128.156
 units:
  - name: etcd2.service
    command: start
  - name: fleet.service
    command: start

write_files:
    -  path: /etc/systemd/network/enp0s8.network
       permissions: 0644
       owner: root
       content: |
         [Match]
         Name=enp0s8

         [Network]
         Address=192.168.128.156/22
         Gateway=192.168.128.1

users:
- name: test
  passwd: $1$yxV9YDKT$s.fAj5dlFyrPwrH0xAQJy/
  groups:
  - sudo
  - docker

#cloud-config

ssh_authorized_keys:
  - ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1y...

hostname: core002

coreos:
 etcd2:
  name: core001
  discovery: https://discovery.etcd.io/86567bce070bd5316bdc9357ee2600de
  # private networking need to use $public_ipv4:
  advertise-client-urls: http://192.168.128.157:2379,http://192.168.128.157:4001
  initial-advertise-peer-urls: http://192.168.128.157:2380
  # listen on the official ports 2379, 2380 and one legacy port 4001:
  listen-client-urls: http://0.0.0.0:2379,http://0.0.0.0:4001
  listen-peer-urls: http://192.168.128.157:2380

 fleet:
  public-ip: 192.168.128.157
 units:
  - name: etcd2.service
    command: start
  - name: fleet.service
    command: start

write_files:
    -  path: /etc/systemd/network/enp0s8.network
       permissions: 0644
       owner: root
       content: |
         [Match]
         Name=enp0s8

         [Network]
         Address=192.168.128.157/22
         Gateway=192.168.128.1

users:
- name: test
  passwd: $1$yxV9YDKT$s.fAj5dlFyrPwrH0xAQJy/
  groups:
  - sudo
  - docker
```

I have installed both of nodes successfully, but when I try to run:

```
 core@core001 ~ $ fleetctl list-machines
 MACHINE        IP      METADATA
 cd08747e...    192.168.128.156 -
```

I get only one machine. The same on the second node:

```
core@core002 ~ $ fleetctl list-machines
MACHINE     IP      METADATA
753caf1b... 192.168.128.157 -
```

I suspect that there may be something wrong with etcd, but going through tons of google references - I didn't found anything useful for this case.

Could you please help me with this issue ?

I'm just starting with studying of CoreOS so some of aspects are unclear for me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created two separate single-node etcd clusters. The etcd logs might have a hint as to why. I would guess that duplicating the name `core001` may have contributed.

Comment: You are right I noticed it. Also I did a great mistake: I created incorrect amount of nodes because I generated discovery token for 3 nodes but created 2. Therefore etcd2 made a great bunch of warning logs with errors towards it. Once I created sufficient number of nodes for generated token and correctly renamed core001 - It worked out fine for me. Great thanks!